# Document Scanning from USB Scanner with VueJs

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Can I develop the vuejs component for document scanning from USB Scanner ? 
I search for this but always I find for c# or java . I want to connection from browser in vuejs system .
But I want to don't need to download the installer for scanner .
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Vue question, but more a web development question. Can your browser access the USB scanner. Most likely no because hardware access for the web is pretty limited. You've got access to the camera, compass, accelerometer, but not generic items connected via USB.

There is a spec for USB access (https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) but as far as I know this isn't supported anywhere yet: https://caniuse.com/#feat=webusb. Ok, it's supported on Chroe, but that's it.